# php createFromFormat fails with datepicker

Tags: php, datepicker

I have the below datepicker in my form:

```
$( '.datepicker' ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
```

Then in my php code which processes the form i have:

```
$campaignDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-y', $formdata['Campaign']['campaign_date']
        );

        if ($campaignDate) {
            $campaignUnixDate = $campaignDate->getTimestamp();
        } else {
            $response = array(
                'status' => 'FAILED',
                'message' => 'Failed to create Campaign Date',
                'redirect' => ''
            );
            echo json_encode($response);
            return;
        }
```

$campaignDate seems to always false, i assume i have the wrong format for my createfrom but i cant work out the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

Use a uppercase `Y` instead of a lowercase `y`

```
$campaignDate = DateTime::createFromFormat(
   'd-m-Y', 
   $formdata['Campaign']['campaign_date']
);
```

### Explanation

The date formats don't match

```
$( '.datepicker' ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
```

would return

> 18-07-2015

while

```
$campaignDate = DateTime::createFromFormat(
   'd-m-y', 
   $formdata['Campaign']['campaign_date']
);
```

uses the format

> 18-07-15

From the PHP docs:

> > **Y**
> >     A full numeric representation of a year, 4 digits
> >     Examples: 1999 or 2003
> >
> > **y**
> >     A two digit representation of a year (which is assumed to be in the range 1970-2069, inclusive)
> >     Examples: 99 or 03 (which will be interpreted as 1999 and 2003, respectively)
>
> http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php